# Where can I find the server config that I am using to send emails with sendmail in CentOS 5.6?

Tags: centos, email, sendmail

I have a CentOS 5.6 VM and have been able to send emails from my PHP application up until two days ago.

I am trying to find the SMTP server config details in my sendmail files somewhere, but I cannot find it.

Shouldn't there be something that references a SMTP server?

This is the closest I have as yet:

```
[root@crmpicco mail]# sendmail -d0.1 -bv
Version 8.13.8
 Compiled with: DNSMAP HESIOD HES_GETMAILHOST LDAPMAP LOG MAP_REGEX
                MATCHGECOS MILTER MIME7TO8 MIME8TO7 NAMED_BIND NETINET NETINET6
                NETUNIX NEWDB NIS PIPELINING SASLv2 SCANF SOCKETMAP STARTTLS
                TCPWRAPPERS USERDB USE_LDAP_INIT

============ SYSTEM IDENTITY (after readcf) ============
      (short domain name) $w = localhost
  (canonical domain name) $j = localhost.localdomain
         (subdomain name) $m = localdomain
              (node name) $k = dev53.localdomain
========================================================
```